# TcpListener often gets connections from browser AJAX calls with no data

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, sockets, xmlhttprequest

ave a simple "Http listener" implenentation using the async Tcp Accept pattern

Server code:

```
public void listen(object token)
{
    listener = new TcpListener(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));
    listener.Start();
    listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(DoAcceptTcpConnection, listener);
}

protected void DoAcceptTcpConnection(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    TcpListener listener = (TcpListener)ar.AsyncState;
    TcpClient client = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar);
    client.NoDelay = true;
    m_token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(DoAcceptTcpConnection, listener);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new HttpProcessor(client, this).process);      
}
```

Process Code for a Connection

```
NetworkStream netStreamRaw = socket.GetStream();

try
{
    // we can't use a StreamReader for input, because it buffers up extra data on us inside it's
    // "processed" view of the world, and we want the data raw after the headers
    inputStream = new BufferedStream(netStreamRaw);
    // we probably shouldn't be using a streamwriter for all output from handlers either
    outputStream = new StreamWriter(new BufferedStream(netStreamRaw));

    // process the http request here...

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("error");
    Log.Error(e);
    writeFailure();
}
finally
{
    outputStream.Flush();
    socket.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
    socket.Close();
    inputStream.Close();
    outputStream.Close();
}
```

On IE (and sometimes Chrome, but only rarely), doing a simple JQuery AJAX GET call results in 2 socket connections (I can tell from debugging) hitting the TcpListener, one of which will be the "normal" http data and one connection will be one that has the NetworkStream.DataAvailable property set to false, and when I call Stream.Read, it just hangs for a few minutes and evetually will give back zero bytes read.

My question is: what **are** these zero data socket connections IE and sometimes Chrome send? Are they something I should be handling in a different way - like are they a kind of 'ping'?

Comment: `DataAvailable` says whether or not there's any data available *right now*. It doesn't say anything about whether more data might be available soon... it's not at all clear that there are any bogus connections - they can just be connections where the connection has been established and the data is coming, it just isn't available yet...

Comment: Right, and that's what I've read elsewhere like I alluded to in my Q. So what do you propose: do I just let the Read block for minutes until it eventually times out? And if that's true, why does IE send 2 connections for a GET AJAX request, one of which ALWAYS has the full request data available right away and the other which seems to have nothing?

Comment: You can set timeouts, of course, so that it's not blocking for minutes - or do it all with async IO to avoid tying up threads. As for browser-specific details, I wouldn't like to say - you'd have to get out Wireshark and look at *exactly* what's happening on a packet-by-packet basis...

Comment: I'm already handling the TcpClients via an async pattern, but I guess the stream I/O could be done that way as well. I've debugged and dug into the sockets connections and each has a distinct remote endpoint port number, so they really are 2 separate connections, one of which just seems to be there for no reason, with no data, hence me calling it 'bogus'. Maybe I just don't understand browser AJAX calls enough. Maybe I'm supposed to do something with the seemingly useless socket that I'm not aware of. The Wireshark thing is a good idea

Comment: UPDATE: for Q #1: Jon Skeet is right, I shouldn't use the DataAvailable. Interestingly enough, once I changed the pattern to take away the check for it and just let the "bogus" socket try to read, it actually cut down on the 'net::ERR' I was getting from Chrome. Still, I'd like an answer to Q #2 - I still don't understand why these socket connections are made from the browser from AJAX calls when they are just sockets with no data. With my new pattern, I'm back to letting the NetworkStream.Read call block and take forever to eventually give back zero bytes read, which seems really odd.

Comment: I suggest you rewrite the question to only ask about what you're interested in, and clarify it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73351/discussion-between-stonedauwg-and-jon-skeet).

Comment: I have been having just this kind of problem in a case where I have an instance of IE9 pointing to a local proxy server on port 8080 using 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' in the URL. The problem goes away when I use the name of the server in the URL. One of our team has suggested that this might be due to the loopback address kicking off both IP4 and IP6 requests, though we have not yet looked at whether this is the case.